# social sharing in ionic 3 always return cancelled

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to implement social sharing feature in my ionic 3 app. Below is the code.

```
facebookShare(index){
    alert('FB Share clicked'); // this works
    this.socialSharing.shareViaFacebook(this.detail, null, null).then(() => {
        alert("Facebook: Success");
    }).catch((error) => {
        alert(error); // this alerts 'cancel'
    });
}
```

As you can see from comments it returns cancel in catch. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Since the 2nd and 3rd parameter are nullable, consider not explicitly sending null in as parameters. Is this.detail a string? Are you sure?

Comment: I removed null parameters and changed the this.details into a string but still the same issue.

Comment: Any help here. I am still trying to make this work.